# GNOME Boxes: How can I route through the host's VPN connection from a Windows guest?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, gnome

I have a Windows 8.1 virtual machine (a www.modern.ie one) running in GNOME Boxes. My host connects to my work network via OpenVPN, and I'd like to access some of the resources from the Windows VM. What do I need to configure to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I do use Gnome Boxes as well, running a Win 7 VM. I never had any issues about VPN connections from the VM when the host is connected.

If you have some static routes on OpenVPN, maybe will be necessary to set them up also in the VM.